# Script for ssh Agent Management: Is this adequate? Any bugs?

Tags: bash, ssh

The following is something I use to manage my ssh agent settings.

```
#!/bin/echo "Must source this:" 
## Ensure that ~/.ssh/env contains valid values

unset SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_ENV_REFRESH

[ -r ~/.ssh/env ] && . ~/.ssh/env
[ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]  || {
    # No env file (or it's badly corrupted:
    eval $(ssh-agent &>/dev/null) &> /dev/null
    SSH_ENV_REFRESH=1
    }

# Ping the agent process:
kill -0 "$SSH_AGENT_PID" >& /dev/null || {
    # No process, so start a new one:
    eval $(ssh-agent &>/dev/null) &> /dev/null
    SSH_ENV_REFRESH=1
    }

ssh-add -l &> /dev/null
[ "$?" -gt 1 ] && {
    # Process alive but unable to be contacted
    # for some reason (wedged/defunct process,
    # or damaged/corrupt UNIX domain socket node?)

    # So kill it:
    kill "$SSH_AGENT_PID" >& /dev/null
    # ... with extreme prejudice if necessary:
    kill -0 "$SSH_AGENT_PID" >& /dev/null \
    || kill kill -9 "$SSH_AGENT_PID" >& /dev/null

    # ... and start a new one
    eval $(ssh-agent &>/dev/null) &> /dev/null
    SSH_ENV_REFRESH=1
    }

[ -z "$SSH_ENV_REFRESH" ] || {
    # Over-write old env file:
    printenv | grep "^SSH_A" > ~/.ssh/env
    # Append export command:
    echo "export SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >> ~/.ssh/env

    # Load the (null-passphrase) identites into the agent:
    ssh-add  < /dev/null &> /dev/null
    }
```

It's intended to be sourced (`. ~/lib/sshagent.sh`) from *~/.bashrc* or other login or
shell start-up files ... or even cron jobs.  It works for me but I'm hoping folks here will review it and offer suggestions about any corner cases that I'm missing.

I used to only run it from ~/.bash_login ... but then I'd find that, in some cases, my shells
wouldn't pick up the settings (X display manager and I think remote ssh non-login sessions ... cases where ssh is called with a command).  In some other cases the old settings would persist and not updated when an agent process was restarted (for whatever reason).  So I run it in *~/.bashrc* and try to avoid any stray output ... as is recommended for *~/.bashrc* in general.

So, are there any evident corner cases or bugs? Would this make sense for something like */etc/bashrc*?  Is it reasonably portable to other shells?

Answer (score 2):

One portability issue in your script is the use of `&> /dev/null` to redirect both stdout and stderr.  This is a bashism and won't necessarily work on other shells. (I was recently bitten by this one.)  The more portable way is to use `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you writing your own? why not use a handy dandy little product called `keychain`?

Here's [Gentoo's Keychain Guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml) (possibly newer version of [same article on Funtoo](http://www.funtoo.org/en/security/keychain/intro/))

It's basically a  little program that allows you to use password protected keys, without typing the password all the time. (It should be available on whatever distro you're using)

You may also be interested in Gentoo's Open SSH Key Management series: [part 1](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/openssh-key-management-p1.xml), [part 2](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/openssh-key-management-p2.xml), and [part 3](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/articles/openssh-key-management-p3.xml). Which looks like it includes some things that you're trying to do.